# Obj-C - Set tableview row as selected on load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have certain cells/rows on my tableview that should be set to 'selected' when the view is opened. In my code below, if the data source contains a specific user id, a green check mark should appear (this part works), and the row should be 'Selected'. That said, the selected state doesn't seem to work. How can I set a cell as selected?

**ViewController.m**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     
    NSDictionary *client = self.sectionClients[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

    static NSString *ClientTableIdentifier = @"ClientTableViewCell";
        
    ClientTableViewCell *cell = (ClientTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ClientTableIdentifier];
        
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClientTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }           
    
    NSString *photo = client[@"client photo"];
     
    cell.clientName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", client[@"first name"], client[@"last name"]];

    cell.subtext.text = client[@"phone"];
        
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:photo];

    [cell.clientPhoto setImageWithURL:imageUrl];
        
    if (self.selectionData != NULL && [[self.selectionData valueForKey:@"clients ids"] containsString:client[@"nid"]])
    {
        
        cell.greenCheck.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"added.png"];
    
        [cell setSelected:YES];
    }
  
        return cell;
        
    
}
```

Comment: In my experience, the best place to add any last minute visual changes to a cell is in `willDisplayCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setSelected` on a cell only sets the selected state for that cell, not for a row in the table. The selected state for a cell simply affects its appearance. It does not affect the selection state of the row itself.

Since cells can be re-used, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function should also clear the selected state if the cell is being used for a row that should not be selected.

In order to put a `row` into the selected state, you will also need to call `selectRowAtIndexPath` for each row that you want to be selected, even ones that are not currently displayed. So you should not call it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because that will only select rows that have actually been displayed.

I am not sure when the best time would be to call `selectRowAtIndexPath`. It would have to be after the table view has called `numberOfRowsInSection` for each section in the table. You can try selecting the rows from `viewDidAppear`. If the table is not ready at that time, then you may have to keep track of when `numberOfRowsInSection` has been called for every section.

Answer (score 0):

Lots to discuss, but to give you a couple ideas...

First, you need to inform the table view that a row is selected using `selectRowAtIndexPath`.

One way to do that is to pass the row(s) you want pre-selected to the table view controller and then selecting the rows in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Note that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called many times throughout the controller's life-cycle, so you'll only want to do this once.

Also, you want to make sure you are tracking the selected state in your **data source**.

Assuming we pass an array of `NSNumber`:

```
@interface ClientTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *preSelectedRows;

@end
```

and using a very simple object model like:

```
@interface ClientObject : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (assign, readwrite) BOOL selected;
@end
```

you would set the `.selected` property in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
// set .selected property for rows we're going to pre-select
for (NSNumber *n in _preSelectedRows) {
    clientData[[n integerValue]].selected = YES;
}
```

and then, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    
    // viewDidLayoutSubviews is called many times during controller lifecycle
    // so we only want to do this ONCE
    if (_preSelectedRows) {
        for (NSNumber *n in _preSelectedRows) {
            NSIndexPath *p = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[n integerValue] inSection:0];
            [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:p animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        }
        // clear the array so we don't call this again
        _preSelectedRows = nil;
    }

}
```

You can also save yourself a lot of effort by having your **cell** class handle the visual representation. Something like this:

```
@interface ClientTableViewCell()
{
    UIImage *selectedImg;
    UIImage *unselectedImg;
}
@end

@implementation ClientTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        selectedImg = [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"checkmark.square"];
        unselectedImg = [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"square"];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    self.textLabel.textColor = selected ? [UIColor redColor] : [UIColor blackColor];
    self.imageView.image = selected ? selectedImg : unselectedImg;
}

@end
```

and your `cellForRowAt` becomes simply:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ClientTableViewCell *cell = (ClientTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:clientTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // we only need to set the name, because the cell class will handle
    //  visual appearance when selected
    cell.textLabel.text = clientData[indexPath.row].name;

    return cell;
}
```

Here is a complete example: https://github.com/DonMag/PreSelectExample